# sphere with projective structure

Tags: projective-geometry

In " Geometric structures on low-dimensional manifolds " , section 2 , we have : 
given a projective tame 3-manifold with radial ends , each end surface has a projective structure since a developing image from manifold induces a developing map from a component of a neighborhood of an aend which homeomorphic to a surface times R to R3 where lines all map to radial lines from a point.since the set of lines ending at a given point of RP3 form a sphere with projective structure , it follows that each end surface has an induced projective structure ".
why the set of lines ending at a given point of RP3 form a sphere with projective structure ?

Comment: Could you please give us some motivation for this (as per http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask)

Comment: @DAVID (not David Roberts!): You should first try to understand  topology of the space of lines through the given point in the 3-space. Then see if you can figure out by yourself if this space has a natural real projective structure. If you cannot do this, I suggest you start reading a different book (maybe Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology").  